# How to prevent sql ant task from printing ‘null’ for non-matching row fields of a left joined table

Tags: oracle11g, ant

The title  says it all I guess... I am using ant 1.8, I sm surprised to realize the comma delimited output file of my ant sql task with a select query has ‘null’ printed for fields from a left joined table where matching rows are not present for a given row in primary table. Issue seems to be how ant ‘exports’ the result set, and how these fields are wrapped in the select clause to print empty string(nvl/nvl2/case to print empty string ‘’ still outputs null via ant task. But if I nvl/nvl2/case to print non empty string say ‘ ‘ works fine as expected) makes no difference.

Toad for Oracle ‘export’ functionality  has a nice ‘include null text’ check box to control the behavior in this context.

I am hoping there is such simple sql task parameter but Google search isn’t particularly friendly to me today.. :(

Any help much much appreciated